# How to navigate from current html page to another html page in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

I'm working on django app and i'm facing a problem when i need to navigate from my index.html page to another about.html page. I'm setting everything in this way below:

**urls.py (myproject)**

```
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('weather_app.urls')),
    path('about/', include('weather_app.urls'))
]
```

**urls.py (myapp)**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('about/', views.about, name="about")
]
```

In index.html, everything is working well, so i will not put the code.

**and in view.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests

def about(request):
   return render(request, "about.html")
```

i have the code below in my index.html:

```
<a href="/about.html/">About </a>
```

and i cannot get about.html page when click About link as you can see above.

Can anybody help me? 
 
Thanks in advance..

Comment: You don't have a page with the URL "/about.html/". You have one with the URL "/about/".

Comment: Remove the 'about' url in your project's `urls.py`. The way you've written it dosn't work unless you mean `/about/about/`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use [this tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#url) to avoid manual rendering of urls.
In your code:

`<a href="{% url 'about' %}">About </a>`

Let me know if this works!